# Why the image was not appearing in the following layout in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

The following is the layout design when click on pushpin showing the follwing layout.in that image was not visible ?please tell me

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemsStyle" TargetType="sltkit:MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="sltkit:MenuItem">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                           Margin="24,0" 
                                           FontSize="26"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                           TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
                                           Margin="24,0" 
                                           FontSize="22"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DatetimeAdded}" 
                                           TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
                                           Margin="24,0" 
                                           FontSize="22"/>
                                <Image  Source="/MyBuddies;component/Images/decline.png" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="200,0" Stretch="Fill" Name="imgDecline" >
                                </Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

all textblock values are binding but image was not appearing in the layout.please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the image set as a Resource in the project for it to display.

I think they are typically added as content items.

HTH
Rupert

Comment: yes i set it as resource but no use.i think margin problem.can you see once.

Comment: Its not so easy to reproduce your problem in our systems. We are not sure what other controls you placed in the page. So, you first use the same image in a plain page, and make sure it renders. Then try to change the margin values

Comment: how to navigate when click on image in that layout.i placed that layout design code in app.xaml .in that navigationservice not working.

Answer (score 0):

If your image's Build Action is "Resource" then you can access it in the way you specified.

check this [link](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-images-content-vs-resource-build-action) to know more about build types and their usage.